# Javafx Pane vs Region?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

According to the documentation, both Region and Pane will resize any resizable child nodes to their preferred size, but will not reposition them.

So i can't see where the differencies between these two containers remain and when use one or another.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`Region` is a superclass for components that have child nodes.

The difference is that `Region` doesn't allow to manipulate its children through the public API. The `Region.getChildren()` method is protected:

```
new Region().getChildren().add(...); // doesn't compile
new Pane().getChildren().add(...); // works
```

Why is that?

Because `Region` is dedicated to component developers, and it allows them to choose if they want to allow API users to work with children directly (like `Pane`, `HBox`, etc.) or not (like charts).